# Add a "if" to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am currently working on a html page which contains a javascript function, and I would like to add a "if" so the function gets activate only when the page's width is more than 500px.
Here is the function :

```
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td>");
});
```

I thought I should add something like  `"if (screen.width > 500px)"` but I don't know how to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? A simple search for 'Javascript screen width' has some questions/answers you might find usefull.

Comment: you just need to remove the 'px' from the 500 in your if statement.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any actions you've taken to solve problem yourself. It needs to be edited or removed.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($(window).width() > 500) {

}
```

Is what you need! Like this:

```
if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td>");
}
```

Comment: Put the stuff inside your function closure inside the brackets here. Or you could put all what you showed inside here, but I would omit the first and last lines.

Comment: `<script>
if ($(window).width() > 500) { $(function(){
  $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
  $(".post").wrap("<td>");
 });

}
</script>` here is what i did, but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Now the function doesn't work at all, even when the page is more than 500px...

Comment: Can you make an example, there is some other issue with your code. http://jsbin.com/

Comment: So what I am trying to do is to make the content flow horizontally. I made it work but realized that it wasn't really good when the page was watched on a iphone or any small device. So I'm now trying to activate the horizontal scroll only for a width of more 500px.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to use the resize function of jQuery to test if the user is resizing the window.

```
$(function() {
   // Trigger on load   
   resizeTable();

        //Trigger on resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        resizeTable();
    });

    function() resizeTable() {
        if ($(window).width() > 500) {
             ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, complete with script tags and `document.ready` wrapper...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 500) {
            $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
            $(".post").wrap("<td>");
        }
    });
</script>
```